# How Stack Overflow update content on pages?

Tags: discussion

I can see on developer tools that Stack Overflow does not make a single XHR request.  How do they update content on page with

> 4 questions with new activity?

Comment: _And I'm for sure, Meta will not provide that information..._ -- Then why did you ask this question.

Comment: Because, Stackoverflow suggest me to ask here.....

Comment: WebSockets. With a **fallback** to XHR when needed.

Comment: Thanks @Oded for reply... I'm very new on WebDevelopment... I will very glad if you provide few reference to study on that question..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: @Oded y u post answer as comment? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) for the realtime updates.

If a browser does not support them (all modern ones do) or they fail, we fallback to XHR.